# Get session array from different file

Tags: php, arrays, session-cookies

I can't access array from other file and still don't figure it out, whether my data already stored into array or not. Should i put $_SESSION into the function?

Lat3_3a.php

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="Lat3_3b.php">
    Insert number: <input type="number" name="num" id="num" />
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="OK" />
</form>
```

Lat3_3b.php

```
<?php
   session_start();
    $_SESSION["num"] = $_POST["num"];
    if (empty($_SESSION["num"]))
        echo "Please, insert number";
    else {
        $val=$_POST['num'];
    echo " Factorial  " .$val. " ! =  " .factorial($val)."<br/>";
    echo "<a href='Lat3_3c.php'>Link</a>";
  }

    function factorial($val){

         if($val<=1){
            $result=1;
            return $result; 
         }elseif($val>1){
            for($i=1; $i<=$val; $i++){
               $result=$val * factorial($val-1);
         }
         return $result;
         }

         $data=array($val,$result,"12345", "Travis");
         $_SESSION["var"]=$_POST["data"];    
  }
  ?>
```

Lat3_3c.php

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if(empty($_SESSION["var"]))
      echo "Variable not found";
  else
  echo "Data : ". $_SESSION["var"];

?>
```

Comment: well, there is an extra `}` in the Lat3_3b.php-file, which might mess things up, I dunno. However, just logically, your code should work just fine. But you might need to rewrite the sequence of events, like returning after setting the $_SESSION['var'], for instance.

Comment: I think I found your mistake and I think it's related to the post $_SESSION["var"]=$_POST["data"]; Try to check the Post part in the console of your Browser. The POST it's use for An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method when using application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data as the HTTP Content-Type in the request.

Answer (score 0):

Ok looking a bit more in to your code, you need to learn more about the session, post and functions. For that a look at the PHP manual site.
Site http://php.net

For your code to work you need to use something like this:

```
<?php
   session_start();
    $_SESSION["num"] = $_POST["num"];
    $_SESSION["var"]=array();
    if (empty($_SESSION["num"])){
        echo "Please, insert number";
    }
    else {
        $val=$_POST['num'];
        $function_result=factorial($val);
        $data=array($val,$function_result,"12345","Travis");
        $_SESSION["var"]=$data;
        echo " Factorial  " .$val. " ! =  " .$function_result."<br/>";
        echo "<a href='Lat3_3c.php'>Link</a>";
    }
    function factorial($val){

         if($val<=1){
            $result=1;
            return $result; 
         }elseif($val>1){
            for($i=1; $i<=$val; $i++){
               $result=$val * factorial($val-1);
            }
            return $result;
         }
     }
  ?>
```

I'm not looking into your math.